# should I scale down for low-resolution devices?

Tags: responsive-design, screen-resolution, displays

after developing my design, everything is very huge, not messed up, but huge. for example, in 1920px devices, if you make browser smaller everything is alright, but if you use a POS system(with 1024px resolution and 15inch) that the device pixel ratio is very low, everything get huge. you can try to see almost any app by setting your monitor resolution at 1024px. generally it's not a problem for any other app, since I checked lots of them, and ask many designers and developers, but they don't have any similar issues. but our main users use this type of device and I want them to have better experience.

I don't know if there is any scaling solution. or anything I can change?

Comment: Are you setting sizes using absolute measures (pixels), or relative measures (density-independent pixels)? The latter approach is designed to take care of the issue you have described. I wrote a blog about this issue, using mobile displays as examples - https://medium.com/lattice-what-is/pixel-perfect-d25fc18bde1e

Answer (score 1):

If you are including specific hardware specifications as part of your design requirements, then you should try to come up with some design solutions that will accommodate the needs of customers or users.

However, you would also then need to consider if the hardware is likely to change over time as well, in which case the solution still needs to be on the software side rather than tailored to the hardware.

I don't see any reasons why the interface can't be designed to be responsive or adaptive to the different types of resolutions (since we already do this for different types of devices such as desktop and mobile phones). You will need to consider both images and UI components and how they can be scaled rather than having to specify exact dimensions for the resolutions.

As suggested in the comments, you need to think about using relative rather than absolute measures in the designs, and then you will be able to scale them to the relative dimensions and resolutions of the display devices.